# как получить доступ ко всем CSS свойствам прописанного класса и поместить их в другой файл, используя python

Tags: html, css, python

Итак, допустим, есть два CSS-файла: один с множеством CSS параметров для определенных классов, типа `.border-top`,`.red-button` и т. д., а другой просто пустой.

И вот когда я назначаю один из этих классов (из первого файла) некоторому HTML элементу, например, `<div class ="border-top"></div>`, я хочу, чтобы код на питоне извлек все свойства и значения записанного класса `.border-top` и поместил их в пустой файл CSS. и так далее с любыми именами классов из первого файла.

как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
css1 = open("a.css", "r") # ввод
# создаём строку со всеми данными. удаляем символ переноса строки
data = "".join(
    [i.replace("\n", "") for i in css1]
)
css2 = open("b.css", "a+") # вывод
neededClasses = ["abc"] # классы, которые необходимо обработать
for i in neededClasses:
    d = re.findall(r"(\.%s.*?{.+?})" % i, data) # получаем стили нужных классов
    css2.write("\n".join(d))
```